# trying to find child mesh within 3D model not working correct in Three js

Tags: three.js

I have a 3D environment made in blender and I am trying to access child meshes (Fox, Dog, Cat) to apply a specific material - I am using using

```
const mesh =  this.el.getObject3D('mesh').getObjectByName('Fox')
```

The problem is that when I apply material through this method

```
        model.setAttribute('transparent-animated-material', '')
```

It is applying it to the other meshes (Fox, Dog, and Cat)

is there a reason this happening?

Comment: Are you using A-Frame or a similar library? Your code does not look like plain `three.js` code.